# How To Run the Installed Application After Setup in Wix?

Tags: wix, wix3

I want to execute the application, I have upgraded. 
http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/run_program_after_install.htm does not work for me as I do not have an Exit dialog.

Comment: yes, no UI. I use quite mode to install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
<Custom Action="LaunchApplication" OnExit="success">CLIENTUILEVEL = 2 AND NOT Installed</Custom>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
```

where Custom action LaunchApplication will execute to open the application.

Comment: In WiX 3.8, this gives the error `"ICE75: LaunchApplication is a custom action whose source is an installed file.  It must be sequenced after the CostFinalize action in the InstallExecuteSequence Sequence table"`

Answer (score 1):

In WiX 3.8, the only way I've found to do this is

```
    <CustomAction Id="LaunchFile" FileKey="..." ExeCommand="" Return="asyncNoWait" />
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="LaunchFile" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Which triggers after the "Install" button in the UI, and before the "Finish" button. Also works fine in `/quiet` mode.